# Copy/Paste Items from listbox to any doc (Excel, Word, .txt) -- VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm unable to copy/paste items from my listbox to any document (Excel, Word, .txt). I would need to select multiple items in the listbox. I searched for it but there seem to be multiple vague answers around there. Can anyone guide me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All you need to do is allow `SelectionMode` to `MultiSimple` or `MultiExtended` then you can use SelectedItems collection to copy to clipboard in KeyDown event of listbox

Simply put

`ListBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple` in `form.load` Event

and use this code (note: listbox is named as `ListBox1`)

```
Private Sub ListBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.KeyDown

    If e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.C Then
        Dim copy_buffer As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        For Each item As Object In ListBox1.SelectedItems
            copy_buffer.AppendLine(item.ToString)
        Next
        If copy_buffer.Length > 0 Then
            Clipboard.SetText(copy_buffer.ToString)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I just removed - MessageBox.Show("Copied Items to Clipboard") -  Stackoverflow is awesome!

Comment: I know this is really old, but for other needs (such as mine), you can also adapt this code for single-item copy/paste. For the life of me, I don't know why this isn't default behavior, but thanks to Rajeev for getting me 90% there!

Comment: It's probably useful to add a `e.SuppressKeyPress = True` to avoid selecting the first item that starts with a C.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a richtextbox and add this:

```
For x As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(ListBox1.Items(x).ToString & Environment.NewLine)
Next
```